# Unable to catch login exception P4API.net - .NET7.0/WinUI3

Tags: c#, .net, exception, perforce, p4api.net

I am working on catching a simple login exception (in the event of an incorrect password entry) for an application I am building for internal use. All of my p4api code works fine for connection, login, client creation, syncing, etc but I cannot seem to catch exceptions and display them no matter what I try.

The exceptions are caught no problem by the debugger

`Perforce.P4.P4Exception: 'Authentication failed.'`

[Exception caught by debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T37Ab.png)

Catch doesn't seem to work whether I use `catch (P4Exception ex)`, `catch (Exception ex)`, or `catch` with no types.

Current code block:

```
public void PerforceLogin(){
    var P4USER = CurrentUserName; //established as current logged in user globally
    P4PORT = locationSelectText.Split('(')[1].TrimEnd(')');
    var P4PASSWD = p4PasswordBox.Password;
    var srv = new Perforce.P4.Server(new ServerAddress(P4PORT));
    var p4 = new Perforce.P4.Repository(srv);

    var p4Options = new Perforce.P4.Options();
    p4Options["-a"] = null;
    try
    {
        p4.Connection.Login(P4PASSWD, p4Options);
    }
    catch (P4Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception caught: " + ex.Message);
        //DisplayDialogBox(ex.Message, "Login Failed");
        return;
    }
}
private void p4LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PerforceLogin();
}
```

Currently have my DisplayDialogBox method noted out to rule out any issues stemming from that but still nothing in my Debug output either unfortunately.

I've also messed with setting `P4Exception.MinThrowLevel = ErrorSeverity.LEVEL` to various levels with no real success.

I don't have a ton of experience with catching exceptions, especially from non-.Net sources but it seems like it should be pretty straight forward?

EDIT to add Call Stack:

```
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.P4Exception.Throw(string cmd, string[] args, Perforce.P4.P4ClientErrorList errors, Perforce.P4.P4ClientInfoMessageList details)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.P4Server.RunCommand(string cmd, uint cmdId, bool tagged, string[] args, int argc)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.P4Command.RunInt(Perforce.P4.StringList flags)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.P4CommandResult.P4CommandResult(Perforce.P4.P4Command cmd, Perforce.P4.StringList flags)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.P4Command.Run(Perforce.P4.StringList flags)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.Connection.Login(string password, Perforce.P4.Options options, string user)
p4api.net.dll!Perforce.P4.Connection.Login(string password, Perforce.P4.Options options)
OMIT.dll!OMIT.Views.MainPage.PerforceLogin() Line 419
    at OMIT\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs(419)
OMIT.dll!OMIT.Views.MainPage.p4LoginButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 971
    at OMIT\Views\MainPage.xaml.cs(971)
Microsoft.WinUI.dll!WinRT._EventSource_global__Microsoft_UI_Xaml_RoutedEventHandler.EventState.GetEventInvoke.AnonymousMethod__1_0(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e) Line 8184
    at C:\__w\1\s\BuildOutput\obj\x86fre\src\projection\generated\WinRTEventHelpers.cs(8184)
Microsoft.WinUI.dll!ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventHandler.Do_Abi_Invoke(nint thisPtr, nint sender, nint e) Line 26137
    at C:\__w\1\s\BuildOutput\obj\x86fre\src\projection\generated\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.cs(26137)
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
Microsoft.WinUI.dll!ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationStaticsMethods.Start(WinRT.IObjectReference _obj, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.ApplicationInitializationCallback callback) Line 13655
    at C:\__w\1\s\BuildOutput\obj\x86fre\src\projection\generated\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.cs(13655)
Microsoft.WinUI.dll!Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Start(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.ApplicationInitializationCallback callback) Line 312
    at C:\__w\1\s\BuildOutput\obj\x86fre\src\projection\generated\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.cs(312)
OMIT.dll!OMIT.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 31
    OMIT\obj\x64\Release\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\App.g.i.cs(31)
```

Edit to add: Username is auto-pulled from Windows login as our Perforce instance is LDAP authenticated and password is pulled from a password box on the mainform. There are no issues running this with the right password but I'd love to be able to detect bad passwords!

Edit to add Usings:

```
using COD_Workspace_Setup.ViewModels;
using Monitor.Core.Utilities;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Perforce.P4;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
```

Edit to add new snippet. I went ahead and built a standalone project in an attempt to get this working. It's only a PasswordBox and a Button for login. All of the p4 info is hard coded.

```
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Perforce.P4;
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Policy;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using P4LoginTest.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media;

namespace P4LoginTest.Views;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void DisplayDialogBox(string message, string title)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
        {
            ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog();

            dialog.XamlRoot = this.XamlRoot;
            dialog.Style = Application.Current.Resources["DefaultContentDialogStyle"] as Style;
            dialog.Title = title;
            dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "Ok";
            dialog.DefaultButton = ContentDialogButton.Primary;
            dialog.Content = message;

            var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    public void PerforceLogin()
    {
        if (p4PasswordBox.Password.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting Login");
            p4PasswordBox.IsEnabled = false;
            var P4USER = "HARDCODEDUSERNAME";
            var P4PORT = "HARDCODEDSERVERFQDN";
            var P4PASSWD = p4PasswordBox.Password;
            Debug.WriteLine("P4PORT = " + P4PORT);

            var srv = new Perforce.P4.Server(new ServerAddress(P4PORT));
            var p4 = new Perforce.P4.Repository(srv);
            p4.Connection.UserName = P4USER;

            Debug.WriteLine("Starting connection...");
            p4.Connection.Connect(new Perforce.P4.Options());
            Debug.WriteLine("Connection passed");

            var p4Options = new Perforce.P4.Options();
            p4Options["-a"] = null;

            Debug.WriteLine("Starting Login try block");
            try
            {
                p4.Connection.Login(P4PASSWD, p4Options);
            }
            catch (Perforce.P4.P4Exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception CAUGHT, P4Exception");
                DisplayDialogBox("Incorrect password entered, please try again.", "Login Failed");
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception CAUGHT, ALL");
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                return;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Try block passed");
        }
    }
    void p4LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PerforceLogin();
    }
}
```

And the Output from the above:

```
Starting Login
P4PORT = HARDCODEDSERVERFQDN
Starting connection...
Connection passed
Starting Login try block
Exception thrown: 'Perforce.P4.P4Exception' in p4api.net.dll
Exception thrown: 'Perforce.P4.P4Exception' in p4api.net.dll
Exception thrown: 'Perforce.P4.P4Exception' in p4api.net.dll
Try block passed
```

EDIT:
I spun up a WinForms project and copy pasted my login method and the catch still doesn't work.

I did, however, seem to resolve it in a roundabout way. I wrapped the p4 command I run immediately after login in a try/catch statement:

```
            // Get list of top level folders in Depot to build branch select menu
            var opts = new GetDepotDirsCmdOptions(GetDepotDirsCmdFlags.None, null);
            var dirs = new List<String>();
            dirs.Add("//" + projectID + "/*");
            IList<String> target = new List<String>();
            try
            {
                target = p4.GetDepotDirs(dirs, opts);
            }
            catch (P4Exception e)
            {
                DisplayDialogBox(e.Message + "\nPlease retry password entry.", "Login Error.");
                return;
            }
```

The command fails if the password is bad and it returns a P4Exception referencing an error in P4PSSWD which I can use to toss up a dialog window asking to reenter the password. So while I can't catch it at login time I can still catch it in follow up commands that fall back on P4PSSWD for their operation. I plan to read the `e.Message` string to look for a P4PSSWD error to differentiate the error messages but as I've never seen any other error with this command it's a low priority. Hope this helps others!

Comment: Is that `Login` function async?

Comment: @Blindy it isn't. I do use other Async methods but none of them are connected with this. It's called from a button click. Basically, the username is set to the Windows login user automatically, the user enters their password into a password box. When Login is clicked the method grabs the password box's ".Password" contents and runs p4.Connection.Login. It all works totally fine with the right password. Adding some of this to the main post as well.

Comment: Are you sure it's never entering the `catch`?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel it isn't as far as I can tell? Wouldn't my simple Debug.WriteLine snippet write to my debug log? I never get anything in the output besides the P4Exception.

Comment: I'd just put a breakpoint there to be sure, first.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel Add the break to the catch statement? I will add it but nothing I've added to catch has triggered thus far.

Added the line in both catch statements, didn't change anything. Debug log still sees the P4Exception but it isn't being caught.

Comment: Yeah, a debugger breakpoint in the catch. Like, to make sure the debugger steps in there.

Comment: You mean System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();?  That's what I added. Otherwise I am unfortunately unsure of what you're requesting

If I reenable the exception in my exception settings it still gets caught by the debugger but my catch statement just isn't doing it. I am truly stumped.

Comment: I assume you're using Visual Studio, judging from the screenshot. And also that you know what a debugger is. So I'm surprised you don't know what a breakpoint is:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints

Comment: But anyway, `P4Exception`s definitely get caught. I use them regularly at work. The only other thing I can guess is that there's something else called `P4Exception` somewhere and that's being used in the `catch`. What do your `using` statements look like?

Comment: I updated the main post with the usings for you. Break points don't seem to be triggering if I put them inside the catch statement. If I disable the P4Exceptions in my breakpoint exceptions it runs through the try catch (never catching). If I I enable the P4Exceptions the debugger breaks as soon as a bad password is entered. So it's recognized by the debugger but not my code (which you seem to have alluded to). I appreciate you taking the time btw, I am self taught so there are some strange gaps in my knowledge I'm sure.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel I added another snippet. Spun up a new project to simplify and seeing the same results still : /

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel solved with a workaround for now!